# On Wishart Distributions

Tags: probability-distributions

Notation: Let $S$ is a **complex** square matrix. ${S}^H$ denotes conjugate transpose matrix, while $[S]_{k,k}$ denotes the k-th diagonal element, and $S^{-1}$ denotes the inverse matrix.

Let $S=GG^{H}$ be a positive definite matrix where all elements of $G$ are independent **complex** Gaussian distributed. $S$ is said to have a Wishart distribution, written as $S\sim\mathcal{W}_p(n,\Sigma)$ with $p<n$.

My concern: **What are the distributions of $[S]_{k,k}$ and $[S^{-1}]_{k,k}$?** Although these distributions arise very frenquently in applied science (e.g., see [R1]), it does not seems to have proper novel available. I am really interested in such distributions. Can anyone help me, please?

[R1](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1049154): Transmit Selection in Spatial Multiplexing Systems

Comment: The elements of $G$ are independent standard normal, and a diagonal element $[S]_{k,k}$ is the sum of square of k'th row, i.e. sum of squares of i.i.d standard normals, hence chi-squared distributions with k degree of freedom.

Comment: More generally, check "Distribution of Diagonal Elements of a General Central Complex Wishart Matrix", IEEE Communications Letters, V.16 N.9, 2012. 
And for diagonal of inverse, see the post [Marginal distribution of the diagonal of an inverse Wishart distributed matrix](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63316/marginal-distribution-of-the-diagonal-of-an-inverse-wishart-distributed-matrix)